# How does one make div's align correctly to start the layout of a page? (header, left panel and main section)

Tags: html, css

**Description:**

I am trying to learn to align elements such as divs and headers. 
Here's what I have so far > **http://jsfiddle.net/QxV6p/**

Below are the issues:

The "Main section - in red" is not aligned with the blue header on the right hand side.

I have set the width of the body and the header to the same value of 1000px. And I have set the left div (black) to have a width of 20% and the main div to have a width of 79% (both inside the body) leaving a margin of 10px between the two divs.

I believe I have positioned the div correctly using the "position: relative" feature.

Please suggest what is wrong with the code? Also is there a better way of making the divs (in this case the left/black div and the main/red div) align as if they were inline?

I've tried "display: inline" but for some reason it makes the divs disappear. Any help is appreciated.

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <style>
        header {
            max-width: 1000px;
            height: 100px;
            background: blue;
        }

        body {
            max-width: 1000px;
        }

        .left {
            width: 20%;
            height: 2000px;
            background: black;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        .main {
            width: 79%;
            height: 2000px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            background: red;
            position: relative;
            top: -2010px;
            left: 210px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<html>
<header>
</header>
<body>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're likely to get help if you provide a JS Fiddle showing your issue, rather than hoping people will copy your code, create a file and run it themselves.

Comment: "I've tried "display: inline"." You should use inline-block. Go Google the difference.

Comment: don't put any displaying content before body tag. every displaying content must go between <body></body> tags.
and check my answer

Comment: You have now received many solutions... you must accept one of the answer and appreciate the other answers with a vote up which you think are also helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendations:

- Avoid positioning using pixels.
- Avoid floats for layout.
- KISS: if you want your main content to be 80%, set it to 80%. Manually manouvering it into position will take more time and scales poorly.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wMTLp/1/) (I changed some of the sizes for easier viewing in the fiddle)

**HTML**

```
<header></header>
<body>
    <div class="left"></div><div class="main"></div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}

.left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
}

.main {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this code but for some reason there is a margin between the left and main div. Why is this?

Comment: I'm guessing you have a newline between the elements. It counts as a character and as such takes up space.
Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wMTLp/2/) with a workaround.
(Isn't it annoying having whitespace in your browser but it won't show you why when inspecting?)

Answer (score 1):

firstly you need a valid html code

```
<html>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
    </header>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
max-width: 1000px;
height: 100px;
background: blue;
}
.wrapper {
max-width: 960px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.left, .main {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:10px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.left {
width: 20%;
height: 2000px;
background: black;
}
.main {
width: 79%;
height: 2000px;
background: red;
  margin-left:4px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qkfIK)

Answer (score 0):

use `float:left` on each element

see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qP5BQ/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float:left` instead of using "`top and left position`"

Here is the updated Code:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <header></header>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
body {
    max-width: 1000px;
}
.left {
    width: 20%;
    height: 2000px;
    background: black;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float:left;
}
.main {
    width: 78%;
    height: 2000px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: red;
    float:left;
    margin-left:2%;
}
```

And **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F6SdG/)** for the same

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
header {
max-width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 100px;
background: blue;
}
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.left {
width: 20%;
height: 2000px;
background: black;
margin-top: 10px;
}
.main {
width: 79%;
height: 2000px;
margin-top: 10px;
background: red;
position: relative;
top: -2010px;
left: 210px;
}
.wrapper{
    margin:0 auto;
}
.container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<html>
<body>
<header>
</header>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```